What plugin is this?
Not sure where is best to ask this but I saw a guy in a YouTube tutorial use the below icon/plugin(?) when drawing lines on QGIS. Just want to know what it is? He was drawing nice curves, is it a bezier curve plugin? Or simply an icon for an older version of QGIS?


Please include a link to the tutorial.

That is Bunting Labs AI Vectorizer plugin here
Not the Plugin icon, but the toolbar button for "Vectorize with AI"

LEGEND thankyou so much!
